# Visiting the Plitvice Lakes National Park in April

Tags: national-parks, croatia

Has anyone been to the Plitvice Lakes National Park, Croatia in the second week of April?

I have seen some pictures of the National Park when it's not very green, and the place doesn't seem to be very impressive unless it's lush green. Everything is completely frozen in the winter, but will it be green enough to go there in mid-April?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In April the temperature is usually above 10 degrees Celsius, and the scenery is somewhere halfway between green and "brown". The real pro is, that the place isn't crowded, like it is in the summer months. I would rather visit the lakes in April or May than in the summer.

[You can get weather data from here.](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/plitvice-weather/sisacko-moslavacka/hr.aspx?day=21)

Here are some pictures to help you decide.
[image: Plitvice in April]

[image: Pltivice in April]

[image: Plitvice in April]

Answer (score 0):

I was actually there at the beginning of April (7th April) and half of the lakes (the upper half) was frozen and closed. But the lower parts was magnificent, the waterfalls looks great no matter what time of the year you go. Even not getting the full package, and keeping in mind it was absolutely freezing, it was a great experience, well worth the cold and 4 hour journey time!

Beware though, sometimes the lakes flood and they block off the footpath next to the lake. But a lot of people (including myself), just walk under the tape and carry on.